# Getting Height of DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> The question has been modified. 
>   The Object Object was my mistake.

I'm trying to detect height of some div and then assign that value to another div.

but the code I have written is not getting me a correct answer (I'm not that good with Javascript/Jquery).

> The CSS & HTML is for demo purpose only.

I'm trying to give the left over space height to my `.iframe` class, but using Jquery/Javascript.

My structure is almost similar and the `container` `width` is fluid.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lhs = $('.section-updates').parent().outerHeight();
  console.log(lhs);
  var rhs = $('.customer-focus').parent().height(lhs);
  console.log(rhs);
  var cfH = $('.customer-focus').outerHeight();
  $('.iframe').height(rhs - cfH);
});
```

```css
.section-updates {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: purple;
  float: left;
}
.customer-focus {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.iframe {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="section-updates"></div>
  <div class="customer-focus"></div>
  <div class="iframe"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: jQuery's `height(value)` function returns a jQuery object, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2)

Comment: I think .height() is readonly, Therefore your line starting `var rhs` is incorrent.

Comment: You can pass multiple arguments to `console.log('LHS--------:' , lhs);`

Comment: can someone get me the correct way to do it?

Comment: `console.log( rhs);` is showing object ?

Comment: When you get object in console. try it like `console.log("LHS", lhs)` instead of '+'  use comma ','  to see what's inside

Comment: Guyz, my mistake. While trying to solve it myself, i had added that `parseInt` thing. Please check the Output of snippet added before commenting or answering

Comment: @DurgpalSingh The question has been modified bro.

Comment: ok @DeepakYadav

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can't really understand the question

Comment: @AntalGyuri I've flagged this question to close it. As it wasn't clear. Maybe later i'll ask with more clear approach. you may flag to close it as well. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try to console like this.. it will show the object content

```
   console.log(lhs);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `var rhs = $('.customer-focus').parent().height(parseInt(lhs));` you are setting the height because you are passing the parameter for height function it will obviously return the object after setting the value `parseInt(lhs)`. Use like `console.log("RHS -----",rhs)` or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(lhs))` or if you need only height use `rhs=$('.customer-focus').parent().height();`

Answer (score 0):

In `console.log` replace `+` with `,`. When you use `+` it tries to concat all values to one string and because `lhs` is an object it cannot be simply converted to string, that's why it prints `[object Object]`